# Teamcity - Prevent parallel execution of specific test classes over multiple agents

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I am simultaneously running two agents to test one .net project. They're testing most of the time different branches (release branch + master).

In a few tests i am reading mails from our test company mailbox. Unfortunately it's not that easy to get a second mailbox for the second agent so both of the agent disturb each other a little bit. Is it possible to "lock" these few tests to prevent parallel execution on both agents?

System Specs:

- TeamCity Enterprise 2021.1
- Nunit Runner: NUnit 3
- NUnit Console: 3.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You want to make use of [shared resources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/shared-resources.html).

> The Shared Resources build feature allows limiting concurrently
> running builds using a shared resource, such as an external (to the CI
> server) resource, for example, a test database, or a server with a
> limited number of connections.

Create a resource in the parent project which represents the mailbox. Give the resource a quota limit of one.

In each of the test configurations add a shared resource build feature that requires an exclusive write lock on the resource you just created.

If another build tries to get a lock on the resource and it cannot be satisfied, the tests remain in the build queue.

Comment: But that only works for all of the tests in that test run right? I need some lock for only specific tests in the whole project for example that only 1 test with category "x" can run so the other tests with category "x" wich are testet by the second agent need to wait until that test is finished